# PSA: Pokerstars Home Game Available!

Tags: discussion

I admit it's not a question. It's an announcement.

For those of you who are unaware, I set-up a Pokerstars home game for us to get involved with some **ACTUAL** poker. If you can get online, here are the details...

- If you don't already have it, download the free PokerStars software from [www.pokerstars.com](http://www.pokerstars.com)
- Open the main poker lobby, then click on the Home Games tab
- Click the 'Join a Poker Club' button
- Enter the Club ID number: 589920
- Enter the Invitation Code: betapokergame

That's it! Once I've approved your membership request, we'll be ready to start playing Home Games online together.

If you want to find out more, visit [www.pokerstars.com/homegames](http://www.pokerstars.com/homegames)

Comment: I assume this requires the ability to play on PokerStars (e.g. US citizens need not apply)?

Comment: Sadly, yes. If there is an equivalent feature or setup capable on another site, let's do it there. Alas, I don't make law for the US government. If I did, there would be poker AND free cake for everyone!

Comment: It's less of a legal thing than a "we at Stars no longer want to deal with the BS of US operations" and I can't say that I blame them.